# How to set a case inside onClick method to get RecyclerView items position

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onclick

I have a view with a `button` and a `recyclerview`. In the adapter of the `recyclerview` I have a listener for `OnClick` and `OnLongClick` events, and the methods in my `MainActivity`. I have no problems getting the position of the items in the `OnLongClick`as it's only used by the items in the recycler, but the `OnClick` it's used by the `button` too.

This is the code in the adapter:

@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onClick(view);
        }
    }

```
@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    if (mLongListener != null) {
        mLongListener.onLongClick(v);
    }
    return true;
}


public void setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
}

public void setOnLongClickListener(View.OnLongClickListener listener) {
    mLongListener = listener;
}
```

And the code in my MainActivity:

@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int id = v.getId();
        switch (id) {
            case R.id.new_note_tv:
                ...
                break;
            default :
                int posicion = recycler.getChildAdapterPosition(v);
                final Note selectedNote = notes.get(posicion);
                break;
        }
    }

```
@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    int posicion = recycler.getChildAdapterPosition(v);
    final Note selectedNote = notes.get(posicion);
    ...
}
```

I have managed to do it in the default case, but I'd want to know if there is more efficient way to achieve it in a case, or if I can't use the same `OnClick`method in `MainActivity`, how I should do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is totally OK your code.

There's nothing stopping you from share same click listener among different `View` (as long as you take caution to handle the click properly).

If your click listener becomes bigger, you can then, create a separated listener for to be used if the views from the adapter... Something like:

```
mAdapter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int posicion = recycler.getChildAdapterPosition(v);
        final Note selectedNote = notes.get(posicion);
        // etc...  
    }
});
```

But your code is fine as it is.